# Mongodb aggregate query to compare time in String format

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data saved in db as follow:

collection name: movies:

```
[
  {id:1, name:"abch", start:"12:00 pm", end:"03:00 pm"},
  {id:2, name:"Annabelle", start:"08:30 am", end:"10:00 am"},
  {id:3, name:"Spider Man homecoming", start:"11:30 am", end:"03:00 pm"},
  {id:4, name:"Grudge", start:"10:00 pm", end"00:00 am"}
]
```

I use filter on the movie's start time and end time, like this -- starting:"12:00 pm" ending:"00:00 am"

```
req.query = { starting:"12:00 pm", ending:"00:00 am" }
```

I want all the list of movies where the `start` and `end` timing is between `req.query = { starting:"12:00 pm", ending:"00:00 am" }`

Output data should be:

```
[
  {id:1, name:"abch", start:"12:00 pm", end:"03:00 pm"},
  {id:3, name:"Spider Man homecoming", start:"11:30 am", end:"03:00 pm"},
  {id:4, name:"Grudge", start:"10:00 pm", end"00:00 am"}
]
```

The mongodb `query` I used is:

```
movies.aggregate([
    $or: [
           {"start":req.query.starting},{"end":req.query.ending}
         ]
])
```

But this does not work. I dont know how to do this and dont know where I am going wrong.

I dont want to use `$dateFromSting` or `new Date()` or `ISODate()`

Want to get output with the above and want it to get from mongodb queries. Need Help Please!!!

Comment: Storing date/time values as (even local) strings is a design flaw, you should **never** do that! You could store them for example as `{start: {hour: 11, minute: 30}}` or use a fix date, e.g. `ISODate('1970-01-01T11:30:00')`

Comment: According to your condition, "Spider Man homecoming" should be in the output, because `start = 11:30` is not between `12:00` and `24:00`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I understand that. But data is already stored in that manner. And I need to query on that string it self. There is no possible way to change the datatype. Please help me with the String itself.

Comment: You cannot compare these strings by a date/time logic - period!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommand such a data structure, but one option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      startHour: {$add: [
          {$mod: [{$toInt: {$substr: ["$start", 0, 2]}}, 12]},
          {$divide: [{$toInt: {$substr: ["$start", 3, 2]}}, 60]},
          {$cond: [{$eq: [{$substr: ["$start", 6, 2]}, "am"]}, 0, 12]}
      ]},
      startingHour: {$add: [
          {$mod: [{$toInt: {$substr: [req.query.starting, 0, 2]}}, 12]},
          {$divide: [{$toInt: {$substr: [req.query.starting, 3, 2]}}, 60]},
          {$cond: [{$eq: [{$substr: [req.query.starting, 6, 2]}, "am"]}, 0, 12]}
      ]},
      endingHour: {$add: [
          {$toInt: {$substr: [req.query.ending, 0, 2]}},
          {$divide: [{$toInt: {$substr: [req.query.ending, 3, 2]}}, 60]},
          {$cond: [{$eq: [{$substr: [req.query.ending, 6, 2]}, "am"]}, 0, 12]}
      ]},
      endHour: {$add: [
          {$toInt: {$substr: ["$end", 0, 2]}},
          {$divide: [{$toInt: {$substr: ["$end", 3, 2]}}, 60]},
          {$cond: [{$eq: [{$substr: ["$end", 6, 2]}, "am"]}, 0, 12]}
    ]}
  },
  {$set: {
      endHour: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$endHour", 0]}, 24, "$endHour"]},
      endingHour: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$endingHour", 0]}, 24, "$endingHour"]}
    }
  },
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [{$gte: ["$startHour", "$startingHour"]},
          {$lte: ["$endHour", "$endingHour"]}]
      }
    }
  },
  {$unset: ["stasrtHour", "endHour", "startingHour", "endingHour"]}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kKODDvtNTqC)

Comment: But doesnt this compare starting with start and ending with end only?

Comment: It should not consider the start if it does not match with starting even though end matches with ending

Comment: If the start is after the starting **AND** the end is before the ending, then the movie is between them. This is what the answer is checking...

Comment: How will it change of the start and end is array of object? timings:[{start:"12:30 pm", end:"03:30pm"}, {start:"08:30 am", end:"03:30pm"}] ? What will be the change the query?

Comment: I tired using array. But I get repeated data instead of getting only 1 record if the condition satisfies and if the array has more than 2 objects

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not 100% clear. Based on my comment and also according to @nimrod_serok recommendation a solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.insertMany([
   { id: 1, name: "abch", start: { h: 12, m: 0 }, end: { h: 15, m: 0 } },
   { id: 2, name: "Annabelle", start: { h: 8, m: 30 }, end: { h: 10, m: 0 } },
   { id: 3, name: "Spider Man homecoming", start: { h: 11, m: 30 }, end: { h: 15, m: 00 } },
   { id: 4, name: "Grudge", start: { h: 22, m: 0 }, end: { h: 24, m: 00 } }
])


starting = { h: 12, m: 0 }
ending = { h: 24, m: 0 }

db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         startTime: { $dateFromParts: { year: 1900, hour: "$start.h", minute: "$start.m" } },
         endTime: { $dateFromParts: { year: 1900, hour: "$end.h", minute: "$end.m" } }
      }
   },
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $and: [
               { $gte: ["$startTime", { $dateFromParts: { year: 1900, hour: starting.h, minute: starting.m } }] },
               { $lte: ["$startTime", { $dateFromParts: { year: 1900, hour: ending.h, minute: ending.m } }] },
               { $gte: ["$endTime", { $dateFromParts: { year: 1900, hour: starting.h, minute: starting.m } }] },
               { $lte: ["$endTime", { $dateFromParts: { year: 1900, hour: ending.h, minute: ending.m } }] }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Which is much smaller compared to @nimrod_serok proposal. Some of these conditions are redundant, i.e. you can even reduce them.

Comment: Is there any way to use it only in terms of 12 hr format? I need that actually.

Comment: Can your answer be updated in terms of 12 hour format in place of 24 hr format?

Comment: Because the time gets stored in db is "01:30 am", " 07:00 pm". Not h:12, m:30 or h:14, m:30

Comment: Datatype for start and end is String

Comment: There is no native method to convert such text into a `Date`, i.e. a comparable value. Either you have to write your own cumbersome function (see proposal from nimrod serok) or you use a 3rd party library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) or [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon)